# Vite quasar components not resolved from external library

Tags: vue.js, vite, quasar

I am creating a library that contains some company standard components. It is built upon Quasar components. When I try to use the library it gives the following error: [Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: q-input. If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution via compilerOptions.isCustomElement.

The library vite.config.js:

```js
import { resolve } from 'path'
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'
import dts from "vite-plugin-dts";
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'
import { dependencies, peerDependencies } from './package.json';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    vue(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
    }),
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        { src: '../dev/src/style/*', dest: 'style' }
      ]
    })
  ],
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve(__dirname, '../dev/src/lib/index.ts'),
      name: 'MyComponents',
      fileName: 'my-components'
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      // make sure to externalize deps that shouldn't be bundled
      external: [...Object.keys(peerDependencies), ...Object.keys(dependencies)],
      output: {
        // Provide global variables to use in the UMD build for externalized deps
        globals: {
          'vue': 'Vue',
          'vue-router': 'vueRouter',
          'axios': 'axios',
          'quasar': 'quasar',
          'moment': 'moment'
        }
      },
      plugins: [
        peerDepsExternal()
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

The library components without any Quasar component in them, work in the project application.

### Expected behavior

Quasar components from the library project should be auto imported.

### Current workaround

Define an install function in the library to register the used Quasar components globally:

```js
export const myPlugin = {
    install(app: App) {
        app.component("q-input", QInput);
        app.component("q-icon", QIcon);
        app.component("q-toolbar-title", QToolbarTitle);
        app.component("q-space", QSpace);
        app.component("q-toolbar", QToolbar);
        app.component("q-header",QHeader);
        app.component("q-btn", QBtn);

    }
}
```